# Was Ilya Makoveev cheating?

Tags: cheating

I don't know the veracity of [this link](http://www.chessdom.com/16-players-proceeded-to-foa-world-juniors-blitz-championship-final/), but it says the wunderkind Ilya Makoveev is disqualified for cheating. I could also see [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/chess/comments/4jmet4/ilya_makoveev_chess_in_the_21st_century_gm_ben/) as well. Is it true? What happened actually?

Comment: Could ppease make your quesrion more self-contained?  Right now I have to look through two webpages and possible a video to find out what "this" means.

Answer (score 2):

It's been 1 more month, yet I can't find anything new on Google (beyond your original post's links) to the same effect. I found only one related item, and it's speculation to the contrary (the speculation consists essentially of a CIA agent, a worm, and a chess engine).

I can't guarantee this, but I suspect the Makoveev-cheating story to be an internet rumor.

*Speculation to the contrary:*
http://chessvdk.ru/forum/index.php?topic=459.235;wap2